# object variable or with block variable not set while running macro

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to run below macro while doing so it gives me error"object variable or with block variable not set".

My Code:

```
    Dim i As Long
Public WithEvents olInboxItems As Items

Public Sub Application_Startup()
  Dim objNS As NameSpace
  Set objNS = Application.Session
  Set olInboxItems = GetFolderPath("Fulfilment.qatar\Inbox\Team Helpdesk May 2016").Items
Set objNS = Nothing
End Sub

Public Sub olInboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    Dim strCat As String

    If Item.Class = olMail Then

    Select Case i
     Case 0
          strCat = "Case 0"
     Case 1
          strCat = "Case 1"
     Case 2
          strCat = "Case 2"
     Case 3
          strCat = "Case 3"
     Case 4
          strCat = "Case 4"
    End Select

    Item.Categories = strCat
            Item.Save
        Err.Clear
     End If
     i = i + 1
     Debug.Print i
     If i = 5 Then i = 0
 End Sub


' Use the GetFolderPath function to find a folder in non-default mailboxes
Function GetFolderPath(ByVal FolderPath As String) As Outlook.Folder
    Dim oFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim FoldersArray As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    On Error GoTo GetFolderPath_Error
    If Left(FolderPath, 2) = "\\" Then
        FolderPath = Right(FolderPath, Len(FolderPath) - 2)
    End If
    'Convert folderpath to array
    FoldersArray = Split(FolderPath, "\")
    Set oFolder = Application.Session.Folders.Item(FoldersArray(0))
    If Not oFolder Is Nothing Then
        For i = 1 To UBound(FoldersArray, 1)
            Dim SubFolders As Outlook.Folders
            Set SubFolders = oFolder.Folders
            Set oFolder = SubFolders.Item(FoldersArray(i))
            If oFolder Is Nothing Then
                Set GetFolderPath = Nothing
            End If
        Next
    End If
    'Return the oFolder
    Set GetFolderPath = oFolder
    Exit Function

    GetFolderPath_Error:
        Set GetFolderPath = Nothing
        Exit Function
    End Function
```

Comment: Erro 91 for below code:

Comment: Public Sub Application_Startup()
  Dim objNS As NameSpace
  Set objNS = Application.Session
  Set olInboxItems = GetFolderPath("Fulfilment.qatar\Inbox\Team Helpdesk May 2016").Items
Set objNS = Nothing
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the following folder path doesn't exist:

```
 GetFolderPath("Fulfilment.qatar\Inbox\Team Helpdesk May 2016").
```

Make sure the specified folder exists in Outlook.

Also I'd recommend using the [GetDefaultFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866724.aspx) method of the Namespace class which returns a Folder object that represents the default folder of the requested type for the current profile; for example, obtains the default Calendar folder for the user who is currently logged on. To return a specific non-default folder, use the Folders collection.

```
 Sub ChangeCurrentFolder()  
  Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace 
  Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")  
  Set Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = _  
  myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)  
 End Sub
```

You may find also the [GetDefaultFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869924.aspx) method of the Store class helpful. This method is similar to the `GetDefaultFolder` method of the `NameSpace` object. The difference is that this method gets the default folder on the delivery store that is associated with the account, whereas `NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder` returns the default folder on the default store for the current profile.